# Should we end the given sentence with TO in the given situation?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, determiners, register, grammar-myths

He's this person who I owe 40$ **(to)**.

He's this person I owe 40$ to.

He's this person who I owe 40$.

Are all these sentences grammatically correct?
Are the first and second one grammatically correct?
Should there be a **to** at the end of first sentence, or should it be more like the last one?

Comment: I am well into my sixties and was taught that we should not finish a sentence with a preposition. In practical everyday speech, native English speakers do it all the time. So is this question about writing or speaking? An editor might well correct a sentence ending with *to*, but a listener would probably not notice you speaking it and ending with *to*.

Comment: @Willow Rex : "whom am I suppose to give this letter to" - Is it incorrect?

Comment: Probably better to say: "To whom do I send the letter?" In writing, that is. In common speech, people might easily and normally say: "Who do I send that letter to?"

Comment: A minor correction: in writing English, we normally put the dollar sign (**$**) in *front* of the number, like **$40**.

Comment: @stangdon  I did not know that. I am sure you are correct. I've just had no occasion to use it.

Answer (score 4):

In all three examples, "this" should be replaced by "the".  Also, the "$" sign is usually written before the number, even though it is said after the number.

With these corrections, option 2 becomes correct in both formal and informal English.

With these corrections, both option 1 and option 3 become correct in informal English.  The contractions are consistent with informal English.  In very formal English, the "who" should be replaced by "whom".

> 1b. He's the person who I owe $40 to.
>
> 1c. He's the person whom I owe $40 to.
>
> 2b. He's the person I owe $40 to.
>
> 3b. He's the person who I owe $40.
>
> 3c. He's the person whom I owe $40.

Another possibility is to put the "to" before "whom", instead of at the end of the sentence.  With this word order, "to whom" is relatively common:

> 4c. He's the person to whom I owe $40.

To my (American) ear, the most natural options would be:

> 5. I owe $40 to him.
> 6. I owe him $40.

Comment: I like your #5 and #6 especially.

Comment: "He's this person" is completely fine in certain colloquial contexts. "I hope I don't run into Kentopher today." "Who's Kentopher?" "He's this person I owe $40".

Comment: @verbose -- I would not use that but am in my 60s. I think language usage changes by generation and that it matters to  older people to speak well -- or at least in the style we were taught. We were taught it was a sign of intelligence. If I am hiring a college grad, I would not take "He's this person" as coming from a person with education -- fair or not. Colloquially, I am down with your answer. :wink:

Answer (score 4):

I am well into my sixties and was taught that we should not finish a sentence with a preposition. In practical everyday speech, native English speakers do it all the time. So is this question about writing or speaking? An editor might well correct a sentence ending with *to*, but a listener would probably not notice you speaking it and ending with *to*. (I decided to make an answer from my comment.)

> He's this person who I owe $40 (to).

speech: -- He's *the* person I owe $40 to. -- in writing: He is the person to whom I owe forty dollars.

> He's this person I owe $40 to.

In speech: -- He's *the* person I owe $40 to.

> He's this person who I owe $40.

speech: He's *the* person who I owe $40 to. --  Writing: He's the person to whom I owe forty dollars.

Comment: I'd give this answer a +1 and say that ending the sentence with a preposition in a written work will impart a colloquial tone, especially if it is not the exception but the rule.

Comment: @TRomano or of course if you are using quotes. Things change, which is why I admitted my age. ;)

Comment: I agree with all you wrote (and was taught the same).  It survives as a stylistic convention not to overuse prepositions at the end of a sentence if you wish to strike a tone that is not too colloquial.

Comment: @ TRomano What I do not know, could fill a textbook. Thanks for your help.